# AngularJs-elasticSearch: page not updated

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, elasticsearch, angularjs-scope

I'm still new in Angular & elasticSearch. My goal is to key in a new tweet , then after clicking on the add button: the tweet will be indexed in elasticsearch) and a table results of tweets will be updated. here is the html:

```
<html ng-app="meetupAngularJSApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>meetupAngularJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/elastic.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/elastic-angular-client.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="well" ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>New tweet</h1>
    <form name="tweetForm">
        Comment : <input type="text" ng-model="libelle"/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add()">Send</button>
    </form>
     <p>Results</p>
    <p>total={{results.hits.total}}</p>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="result in results.hits.hits">
        <td>{{result._id}}</td>
        <td>{{result._source.message}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**here is my javascript file:**

```
'use strict';

var meetup = angular.module("meetupAngularJSApp",["elasticjs.service"]);

meetup.controller('myController', function myController($scope, ejsResource){
    localStorage.clear();

    /* instantiate (takes an optional url string) */
    var ejs = ejsResource('http://localhost:9200');

    var client = ejs.Request().size(50)
        .indices('twitter')
        .types('tweet');

   function search(callbackFn){

       $scope.results= client
                .query(ejs.MatchAllQuery())
                .doSearch(callbackFn);

   }

search(function(){

        console.log('Search success') ;
    });



    $scope.add = function (){
        var hello = ejs.Document('twitter', 'tweet')
            .source({
                message: $scope.libelle
            });
        hello.doIndex(function(){
            console.log('Success indexing');
            console.log('New search');
            search(function(){
                    console.log('Search success 2') ;
                });

        });
    }
});
```

My problem is that: when I click on the "add" button, the tweet table is not automatically update. I have to refresh the page to get it updated.What I don't understand is that when I consult the console log, I have this:

```
- XHR finished loading:            "http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet". 
 - Success indexing
 - New search
 - XHR finished loading:             "http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search".
 - Search success 2
```

So for me, the code is well executed (as it does actions in order) so $scope.results should be well updated. I don't understand what I have to click on refresh page,  I thought AngularJs would automatically render the page if $scope.results changes.

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Elasticsearch by default does not update the index immediately, and will take a small amount of time before a new document is searchable. You can set `refresh: true` when you index a document to have it be indexed immediately.

Comment: Also I must say I am very surprised the results are available synchronously. Surely the point of the callback passed to the search function is to handle the results? I do not have any experience with the library, just making an assumption from normal JavaScript use. Otherwise the code will block till the search roundtrip finishes, which would be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've done something outside of angular that it doesn't know about. ejs.Document, and hello.doIndex must do ajax calls (or a timeout?) and you have to let angular know when they're finished.

In order to do that add in a scope.$apply(); in a callback (if it's available), it might look like this:

```
    var hello = ejs.Document('twitter', 'tweet')
        .source({
            message: $scope.libelle,
            updateCallback: function(){ $scope.$apply(); }
        });
```

You can read up on the $apply() method here [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)